# Why using Task.ContinueWith hurts my program's responsiveness?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

We have a video player written in WPF with a scroll bar. When the scroll bar is dragged right-left the `CurrentFrameTime` is updated and triggers `UpdateFrames` which, in turn, grabs the frame and shows it. That works fine.

But, sometimes grabbing the frame can take time (because of the disk for example) and though `CurrentFrameTime` value can be already changed, the `UpdateFrames` can be "stuck" and still be waiting for previous frame in `...GetAsync().Result`.
What is decided to do is to move `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` into `ContinueWith` block. Now, each time the `CurrentFrameTime` is changed, the previous operation will be canceled(we don't need to show the frame if frame time was already changed) and an up-to-date frame should be shown. But, for some reason because of this change the application became slower. When I drag the scroll it can take a few seconds before the image is updated.

What could happened that moving the code into `ContinueWith` has slowed down the video player?

**MainApplication without ContinueWith**

```
_threadUpdateUI = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateFrames));

public long CurrentFrameTime
{
  get{...}
  set
  {
     ...
     _fetchFrame.Set();
  }
}

void UpdateFrames()
{
    while(run)
    {
       _fetchFrame.WaitOne();

       var frame = Cache.Default.GetAsync(CurrentFrameTime)
                                .Result;
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ShowFrame(frame.Time, frame.Image)));           
    }
}
```

**Cache**

```
public Task<VideoFrame> GetAsync(long frameTime)
{
    //this i used when cache is disabled
    if (GrabSynchronously)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<VideoFrame>();  
        //reading from file      
        var frame2 = FrameProvider.Instance.GetFrame(frameTime);                
        tcs.SetResult(frame2);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    ...
}
```

**MainApplication WITH ContinueWith**

```
void ShowFrames()
{
   while(run)
   {
      _fetchFrame.WaitOne();

      _previousFrameCancellationToken.Cancel();
      _previousFrameCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

      Cache.Default.GetAsync(CurrentFrameTime).ContinueWith((task) =>
      {
          var frameTime = task.Result.Time;
          var frameImage = task.Result.Image
          Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ShowFrame(frameTime, frameImage)));
      }, _previousFrameCancellationToken.Token);    
   }
}
```

df

Comment: Your GrabSynchronously block could be simplified to `if (GrabSynchronously)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(FrameProvider.Instance.GetFrame(frameTime));
    }`

Answer (score 3):

In your old way your `UpdateFrames` loop would block every `.Result` call. This made your loop self metering, only allowing one request "in flight" at a time even if `_fetchFrame` got `.Set()` called many times while it was waiting for `.Result` to finish.

In your new way every call to `_fetchFrame.Set()` triggers another task to start up and be "in flight" (assuming `GrabSynchronously` is false) even if it never gets used. This is flooding your system with requests and is causing your slowdown.

One possible solution is to put another semaphore of some type to limit the number of concurrent requests for frames you can handle.

```
Semaphore _frameIsProcessing = new Semaphore(5, 5); //Allows for up to 5 frames to be requested at once before it starts blocking requests.

private void ShowFrames()
{
    while (run)
    {
        _fetchFrame.WaitOne();

        _previousFrameCancellationToken.Cancel();
        _previousFrameCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _frameIsProcessing.WaitOne();
        Cache.Default.GetAsync(CurrentFrameTime).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            _frameIsProcessing.Release();

            if(_previousFrameCancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            var frameTime = task.Result.Time;
            var frameImage = task.Result.Image;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ShowFrame(frameTime, frameImage)));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you use a `Semaphore` rather than a `SemaphoreSlim` in this situation? This answer prompted me to look up the use of semaphores, as I wasn't familiar with the concept.

Comment: Because I was writing the answer quickly. `SemaphoreSlim` would have worked fine too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, unfortunately it didn't help. Even if I use `Semaphore(1,1)` allowing only one at a time it still stucks. Probably I'm missing something

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, `GrabSynchronously` is not `false`. It's `true`

Comment: @theateist The other thing it could be is the fact that `ContinueWith` is running on another thread and you are stressing the TreadPool. Try putting `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` as a paramter to the continuation `.ContinueWith((task) => { ...}, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, it didn't help. I noticed that while I hold the thumb of scroll bar and drag it the image is not updated. But, as soon as I release it the image is updated. Maybe the ui requests are always at the bottom they never is executed?!

Comment: The dispatcher is a priority queue, The default [priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx) value is `9` only `Send` priority is higher. I am not sure what is causing your slowness. At this point I would go get a profiler and see if you can spot any hotspots with that.